# Angular2 - unable to get Set-Cookie from auth. response (jaas, wf)

Tags: java, angular, cookies, wildfly, jaas

Iam trying to authenticate from Angular2.1.0 to JAAS form-based j2ee app on WildFly 8.2

```
     let j_username = 'sb2';
        let j_password = 'sb222';
        let url: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/prototype-rest/j_security_check';

        let body = 'j_username=' + j_username + '&j_password=' + j_password;

        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          })
          ;

        //let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers, withCredentials : true});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

        this.http.post(url, body, options)
          .subscribe(
            (res: Response) => {
              console.log('res = ' + res);
              console.log(res.headers.keys());
              var headers = res.headers;
              var setCookieHeader = headers.get('Set-Cookie');
              console.log('setCookieHeader = ' + setCookieHeader);
            },
            err => {
              console.log('err = ' + err);
            }
          )
        ;
```

response from wildfly

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=iyD6Yz_Tj7xsIM1zRDHaR2bh.sk-za-04702; path=/prototype-rest
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
Server: WildFly/8
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie
Date: Thu, 03 Nov 2016 14:01:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
```

My problem is that I am not able to read Set-Cookie, if I use withCredentials : true (I am not sure if I should), response fails ... I'd like to add JSESSIONID to request, where I register websocket ...

Comment: HI @eriskoo, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: https://angular-university.io/lesson/angular-security-browser-cookies-how-to-use-them-for-user-session-management - not sure if this is any help.